# Grub Menu is not appearing even after running`update-grub`

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I downlaoded Ubuntu 18.04 on a USB I have used it on other machines with windows 10 on them.

Now I decided to use it with a Lenovo Yoga, and the grub menu doesn't show up. I had to manually load the kernel and boot.

So after booting I ran `update-grub` but still when I reboot the system I still get directed to the grub shell.

Does anyone know how to fix this as I don't want to always boot Ubuntu manually.

I want that the grub menu should appear and not the shell so I can just press enter and boot :)

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What do you want? GRUB menu to appear or GRUB menu to disappear ?

Comment: @Emmet I want the GRUB menu to appear

Comment: You need to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode, for starters, amd then assure that it is booting "Ubuntu" instead of "Windows" in UEFI settings.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Where can I change those settings?

Comment: I know it's in f2 setup menu, but I tried all combinations and then I press f12 and select my USB to boot from which has the grub.cfg but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MosheRabaev, how did you prepare bootable USB stick for Ubuntu 18.04? Did you install Ubuntu 18.04 on your  `Lenovo Yoga` using USB stick successfully?  Is it dual-booted? If it is so, can you access windows 10?

Comment: @Marmayogi I usually use it with an old Dell computer running Windows 10. Only recently I decided to use ubuntu with a Lenovo Yogo and yes, I have Ubuntu on my USB, and Windows 10 is on the hard drive in the laptop. I can access windows 10 no problem

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `mokutil --sb-state` 2. `ls /sys/firmware/efi/` and 3. `sudo os-prober`. Have you updtated Ubuntu after installation? Can you access Wi-Fi and connect to internet?